# How do I used the linkedin gem to parse a profile in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri, linkedin-api

I am using the linkedin gem https://github.com/pengwynn/linkedin

I authorize using Omniauth and store the access token and secrets.

I then authorize by access with the client.

I appear to get something useful when I type client.profile -- but it looks like mostly Nokogiri but in a LinkedIn::Profile class.

How do I specifically access fields, and will I be able to use method calls from the View in rails or do I need to do all the parsing in the controller and pass those values to the View from there.

Example of how to access the profile image url, title, name, company that sort of thing once I have established client.profile would be great.

When I use the (:fields =>) I get back something like this:

```
#<LinkedIn::Profile:0xb682c72c @doc=#<Nokogiri::XML::Document:0x..fdb41630a name="document" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x..fdb415fae name="person" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x..fdb415d88 "\n  ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x..fdb415d24 name="picture-url" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x..fdb415aae "http://media.linkedis:
```

I just want the string associated with the node "picture-url"...how do I do that?

From controller:

```
7   `def show`
  8     @user = User.find(params[:id]) 
  9     @client = LinkedIn::Client.new(ENV["LINKEDIN_KEY"], ENV["LINKEDIN_SECRET"]) 
 10     @client.authorize_from_access(@user.atoken, @user.asecret) 
 11     @client.profile(:id => @user.uid, :fields => ["picture-url", "headline"]) 
 12     
 13   end
```

New error:

```
undefined method `downcase' for nil:NilClass
```

Here is a related question: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821549/how-do-i-pass-a-a-tag-through-ruby-to-linkedin-using-the-gem"

Comment: Can you post a full backtrace for your downcase error? Are you sure that all the tokens that you have in your example above are in fact not NIL ? try running all the commands in your show method in an IRB console, and see which one of them causes a backtrace and then focus on that command and its arguments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did it by adding:

```
client.profile(:fields => [:positions]).positions
```

This would then allow me to access specific positions or fields without going into the raw xml, just using the methods in the gem.  The gem works nicely once I get the format...

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you get the latest version of linked_in gem from github. It uses Hashie/Mashie syntax which is much simpler than dealing with Nokogiri output and XPath.
If youre using bundler add this to your Gemfile(removing any other linked_in gem reference)

```
gem 'linkedin', :git => "git://github.com/pengwynn/linkedin.git"
```

this version of the gem basically sticks the output of your Linked In search into a hash, so you would access your picture-url string as follows: **profileHash["picture-url"]**

P.S. if you do decide to stick with your version of linked_in gem, get familiarized with XPath syntax, you will need it. Based on the information you provided, the picture url string will be available via **profileXML.xpath("//person/picture-url").first.text**

Comment: hello!  yes, I tried using the git version....maybe I need to do an uninstall first and give it a whirl...thanks, will keep you posted.

Comment: Hi, I did the change, it still looks like it is returning a Linkedin::Profile class with an @doc that is Nokogiri...will update what I have in my controller

Comment: Then you didnt get the right version. Look at the source code of master branch at https://github.com/pengwynn/linkedin/tree/master/lib/linked_in -- there is no Profile class(it does exist in the old version)

Comment: I see...I guess I'm still not clear what to do, then....do I declare the client and then what method do I apply?

Comment: @Vladimir, this is what I show in my bundler -- looks like the most recent.... .bundler/ruby/1.8/linkedin-3b660ce1465c

Comment: If you got the right gem version, then you will need to authenticate the client(see the gem docs) and get the profile from it. See the updated methods here: https://github.com/pengwynn/linkedin/blob/master/lib/linked_in/api/query_methods.rb or perform a search : https://github.com/pengwynn/linkedin/blob/master/lib/linked_in/search.rb Its unfortunate that the docs havent kept up with the code changes, but the code is pretty readable.

Comment: I have authenticated already using oauth -- but having difficulty understanding the docs.... :(

Comment: Unfortunately docs have not kept up with the code, so read the code instead.. there is fairly little of it. Also to get familiar with LinkedIn APi use https://apigee.com/console/linkedin

Comment: @Vladimir I'm still not getting the result you described....I went back to the earlier form of the gem....is there a way to use a Nokogiri parser to turn into a hash?  I can't seem to access the nokogiri document in the LInkedin class....

Comment: Please be specific at what youre getting and update your question, i may be able to answer it.

Comment: @Vladimir, hello output what I get....it is the Nokogiri thing and I don't know how to access specifics -- I also added another question I need help on regarding network updates?

Comment: @vladimir, are you able to help parse...I am pretty sure if I could get at just the nokogiri document, there are tools to use that....

Comment: @vladimir, I looked into the profileXML..I'm still not clear.  What I have is client.profile will give me back the array above where @doc contains the Nokogiri....